# Why I can't use 'require' built in module in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to initialise a very simple server using node.
As I understand 'require' and 'HTTP' are built-in modules which I can use.

So my code looks as the following:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(() => {
  console.log("I hear you!");
});
server.listen(3000);
```

when i run `node server.js` i get the following error:

```
const http = require('http');
             ^
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///D:/Project/ZTM/recobrain-backend/server.js:1:14
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

I tried to install 'require' both locally and globally with the same result.

Finally, I managed to get it work with this piece of code:

```
import * as http from 'http';
```

The question is, why require syntax doesn't work?

Comment: `require` is not a module. By default, node modules use commonJS syntax but you can now use ES modules as well in node. If the extension of your script file is `.mjs` or if `type` property in `package.json` file is set to "module", then you need to use ES module syntax.

Comment: Is your package type set to module? (in your package.json) if so that's why.

Comment: do you have anything which is similar to ""type": "module"" in your package.json. if yes remove that or use "import" instead

Comment: yes, I have: "type": "module"  in my package.json

Comment: _"yes, I have: "type": "module" in my package.json"_ - @KirályRoland that is the reason `require` is not working. Remove it and `require` will work BUT then ES module syntax won't work. You can use either one of them, but not both.

Comment: This was the issue! If some of you can post it as an answer, I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `type: "module"` from `package.js` and you should be able to use `require()` or alternatively you can set it to `type: "commonjs"`

Answer (score 2):

ES Modules in Node 14 and after no longer have require by default.

just put this code at the top of your file:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_createrequire_filename